# Desktop application to work with CSS/JS files for websites

Tags: javascript, css

I was analyzing my website performance and load time, they recommended to minify js and css files

Question is, is their a desktop application such that I give it my css file(s), it minifies it for me and I can change/add new CSS through the application rather than working with the minifed version

Same goes for JS files

Comment: it's called a build process and there's lots to choose from.

Comment: Very, very wide open subject here. It really depends on your environment, but a low friction way to get started is with Grunt, Yeoman, and Node.js

Comment: Which platform are you on?